# mysql select - CONCAT no longer working with MariaDB upgrade

Tags: mysql, mariadb, concatenation, where-clause

This code is part of a database search autocomplete function. It was coded a while ago but the database has since been upgraded from mysql to MariaDB.

This is the part of the code giving an error.

```
$sql = 'SELECT tree_id, tree_common_name, tree_botanical_name FROM all_trees';
for($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
  $sql .= 'WHERE CONCAT(tree_common_name,tree_botanical_name) LIKE ? ';
}
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  $user_error = 'Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . '<br>' . 'Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error;
  trigger_error($user_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}'
```

The error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Wrong SQL: SELECT tree_id, tree_common_name, tree_botanical_name FROM all_treesWHERE CONCAT(tree_common_name,tree_botanical_name) LIKE ? <br>Error: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(tree_common_name,tree_botanical_name) LIKE ?' at line 1 in /home/wiwi1740/public_html/includes/autocomplete.php on line 73
```

I've looked at using 
`$sql .= 'WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',tree_common_name,tree_botanical_name) LIKE ? ';`
but still throws an error.

Any tips would be appreciated. This code originally came from someone else that I adapted for my client.

Comment: I doubt this query ever worked. There's a space missing before `WHERE`... And it also looks strange that the `WHERE` clause can be appended multiple times as it's appended in a `for` loop.

Comment: *CONCAT no longer working with MariaDB upgrade* There is no problems with CONCAT() function in MariaDB. [MariaDB Server Documentation » Built-in Functions » String Functions » CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat/). I think the problem point is in lost space char between `all_trees` and `WHERE` literals.

Comment: Thank you both. I no longer have the error message - so simple. It has brought up a different error from an associated file so I keep digging.
@stickybit yes it does look odd but it has worked 

Comment: In that case, you have only ever had one item in the loop

Comment: `echo $sql` -- The problem may be obvious then.